Having trouble downloading multiple files from aws s3 then zipping them and downloading them in React
I'm trying to download multiple files from aws s3 then zip and download them.
So this code works but I would rather not have the setTimeout and would like to use an async function and wait til all the files are downloaded then zip them.  Appreciate any advice!
        <a
          style={{ color: "#0071CE", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={async () => {
            var JSZip = require("jszip");
            let zip = new JSZip();
            var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
            let tempFolder = zip.folder("temp");

            CRMPhotos?.map((CurrentPhoto, index) => {
              if (CurrentPhoto?.photo_gallery_id === GallerysubmissionData?.id) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                xhr.onload = function () {
                  tempFolder.file(CurrentPhoto?.photo_url?.substring(CurrentPhoto?.photo_url?.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), xhr.response);
                };
                xhr.open('GET', CurrentPhoto?.photo_url);
                xhr.send();
              }
            })

            setTimeout(() => {
              tempFolder.generateAsync({ type: "blob", compression: "DEFLATE" }).then(function (content) {
                FileSaver.saveAs(content, GallerysubmissionData?.photo_gallery_name);
              });
            }, 150 * CRMPhotos?.filter((CurrentPhoto, index) =>
              CurrentPhoto?.photo_gallery_id === GallerysubmissionData?.id)?.length);
          }
          }>Download Gallery&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon
            style={{ color: '#0071CE', marginRight: "15px", marginLeft: "15px", cursor: "pointer" }}
            size="lg"
            icon={faArrowDownToLine} /></a>

